# what is the derivative of $\sec^2x$

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry

I'm using the quotient rule and so I rewrite $\sec^2x$ as $\frac{1}{\cos^2x}$

Then set $u = 1,$  $u'= 0$
then $v = \cos^2x$ and $v'= -2\sin x \cos x$

I then get $\frac{2\sin x \cos x}{\cos^4x}$

but when I simplify that I don't get $2\sec^2x\tan x$ which is the correct answer?
I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: You *do* get $2\sec^2x\tan x$ !

Comment: haha yeah I just simplified it totally wrong. Thanku :)

Comment: If you know what's chain rule, and some simple formulas like derivative of $x^n$ and $secx$, then you can apply chain rule of differentiation to arrive at the answer.  $$\frac{d}{dx}(sec^2x)= \frac{d}{d(secx)}(sec^2x)*\frac{(secx)}{dx} = 2secx*(secx*tanx) = 2tanx*sec^2x$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{2\sin(x)\cos(x)}{\cos^4(x)} = 2\cdot\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos( x)}\cdot\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)} = 2\tan(x)\sec^2(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{2 \sin(x)\cos(x)}{\cos^2(x)\cdot \cos^2(x)}=2 \sec^2 (x) \tan(x)$$

Comment: thanks I completely missed that

Comment: See my edits for correct LaTeX usage.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{2\sin x \cos x}{\cos^4x}=\frac{2(\sin x)}{(\cos x)[\cos^2x]}=2\tan x \sec^2 x$$

Comment: oh gosh I didn't see that, thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You simplified wrong. In $$\frac{2 \sin x \cos x}{\cos^4x}$$  start by cancelling $\cos x$ from top and bottom. Now its

$$\frac{2 \sin x }{\cos^3x}.$$

That's the same as your answer.

Comment: yeah idk what I was doing there, thanks so much!